# Yii framework server error on localhost

Tags: yii, apache2

I'm trying to run a Yii based website on my localhost. I am using apache2 on an ubuntu 12.04 machine.

It works till `localhost/website/`  and displays the directories in that folder:

```
framework/
frontend/
support/
www/
```

To run the website however, I must use `www/` and the moment I click on `www/` it says **Server Error**.

To fix this, I've changed all permissions in my `var/www/website` as

```
sudo chmod -R 755 website
sudo chown -R  website
sudo chgrp -R www-data website
```

As a last resort, I used `chmod -R 777 website`.
Still doesn't work. I think it may be a problem with Yii installed on my machine itself, but the demos in the Yii folder are working properly.

Comment: Can you post the content of index.php in the www folder? Also it would be helpful to us if you can add the following lines in the index.php file at the top:
`ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);`
And post the errors that are shown when navigating to www folder...

Comment: The index.php is having the following code

'<?php

// change the following paths if necessary
$yii = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../framework/yii.php';
$configPath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../frontend/config';
require_once($yii);

defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);

$local = require($configPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'main-local.php');
$base = require($configPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'main.php');
$config = CMap::mergeArray($base, $local);

Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();'

Comment: Sorry for the above comment. Cant edit it now. My index.php is

`<?php 
// change the following paths if necessary 
$yii = dirname(FILE) . '/../framework/yii.php'; 
$configPath = dirname(FILE) . '/../frontend/config'; require_once($yii); defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true); 
$local = require($configPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'main-local.php'); $base = require($configPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'main.php'); $config = CMap::mergeArray($base, $local); Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();`

Comment: Hmmm... seems to be proper... I'm assuming the paths configured are correct and that yii.php is in it's correct place. Can you add the code I had pasted above to the top of the index.php file and run it again to see what the actual error is? The code again: 
`ini_set('display_errors',1); ini_set('display_startup_errors',1); error_reporting(-1);`. This code enables error reporting...

Comment: Yeah that resulted in this: 

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /var/www/ft-website/frontend/controllers/SiteController.php on line 74`

However, there's no error in SiteController.php. As that file is the same as the one online. Paths are correct. However, I'm not sure about yii.php. Where should the correct place be?

Comment: what's on line 74 or thereabouts? yii.php should be just inside the framework folder as shown in this line: `$yii = dirname(FILE) . '/../framework/yii.php';`

Comment: No errors in line 74 as such. I did get past this by changing permissions of basically every directory that was being used. Now my problem is that localhost wont run my phpmyadmis. I gave up and now I'm installing the same on my Windows partition.

Answer (score 0):

Are 'support' and 'frontend' your apps? Moving your app into the www folder is an option, but you will need to correct the path in the index.php entry script to reach the framework. Another option is to use .htaccess rules to point to your app folders. I'm not experienced enough with .htaccess to help you there, however.

Comment: /website is my app and the folders are inside the app. Frontend is holding my MVC folders. So I don't think that's the issue because this is the same structure on the actual website structure and the website works fine.